# Mapping error: Function userCShare:xxxx() has failed

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-deployment

I have a single recieve port, one send port with a map.  THe map has a scripting functoid. When I drop a file in a directory, the biztalk app picks the file up, maps it to a new message and drops a file.

I've deployed, it is picking up the file, end erroring out saying: 
 "Function 'userCSharp:DetermineMessageID()' has failed." 


My map no longer contains this method and does not refere to it.  I can use the test, validate and debug features on the map at dev time and they all work fine.  I've deleted the app, undeployed my assembly containing the map and schemas and redeployed, and still get the error.  Does something else need to be refreshed?

Comment: Might be a bit obvious but have you restarted your host instance(s)?

Comment: Did not realize I would have to do this.  Same if I re-deploy an orchestration.  I guess I just assumed they would take affect if I just stopped and started the application.  If have have several applications, stoping and starting the host instance might not desirable, there's no way around that?

Comment: @Jeremy - In a prod environment, you would typically have a 2 or more node cluster and can load balance the change. If you only have a single node, you would either need to bump up the assembly versions & do side by side switchover, or e.g. Isolate each app on its own BTS host.